# How to specify sibling selector in Less in short way?

Tags: css, less

I have the following less rule:

```
.menu-link {
     & + .menu-link {
        border-left: 1px solid #000;
     }
}
```

It work fine but looks ugly because if my `menu-link` class get changed than I need to replace it two places.

Is there way to simplifying the rule above?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> [**LESS - Parent Selectors**](http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature)
>
> The `&` operator represents the parent selectors of a nested rule and is most commonly used when applying a modifying class or pseudo-class to an existing selector.

Since `&` represents the parent, you could simply use `& + &`:

```
.menu-link {
     & + & {
        border-left: 1px solid #000;
     }
}
```

..which compiles to:

```
.menu-link + .menu-link {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

---

As a side note, `&` refers to the entire parent selector. Thus, if you were to use the following:

```
.parent {
  .menu-link {
    & + & {
      border-left: 1px solid #000;
    }
  }
}
```

..it would compile to the undesired result of:

```
.parent .menu-link + .parent .menu-link {
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Therefore you would need to keep your selectors simple and use

```
.menu-link {
     & + & {
        border-left: 1px solid #000;
     }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer. In case of nested selectors, we could use variables to store the selector name and do selector interpolation like [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myqvbM). This would mean that a change has to happen only at one place. But if there are more such cases it would require more variables and might become messy.